# Import multi-line CSV records into spreadsheet as column data

Tags: csv, libreoffice

Any standard fixes to convert multi-line CSV records into column data (as CSV or LibreOffice)? I'm using ArchLinux and I have LibreOffice (and Python, for what that's worth).

I have a CSV file with records formatted like this:

```
"field1","value1"
"field2","value2"
"field3","value3"

"field1","value1"
"field2","value2"
"field3","value3"

"field1","value1"
"field2","value2"
"field3","value3"
```

And I would like to condition the data into column format:

```
"field1","field2","field3"
"value1","value2","value3"
"value1","value2","value3"
"value1","value2","value3"
```

I didn't see anything relevant in LibreOffice open menu.

Comment: How would you like to accomplish this? Via libre office importing or some sort of macro or regex?

Comment: Efficiently. First, any understanding of the issue as a problem-type would be helpful. My search using the terms above was not fruitful. Second, time-wise, any out of box solution is more preferable to scripting. Third, LibreOffice is the spreadsheet program I have. If a solution is there (and I doubt it), then its tucked away in the app where I can't find it.

Comment: Do you need to keep the quotation marks and commas, or do those represent the columns and the data and are unneeded?

Comment: @Raystafarian. The commas and quotation marks are not part of the text. I'm only representing the contents of the CSV data in the example. The actual imported text does not contain quotations, but it _may_ contain commas.